# Is "he better get" never grammatical to use in any context?

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

1. He better get used to it.
2. He'd better get used to it.

- Is it never correct to write "he better get" in any context? It should always be "he'd better get"?
- Do native speakers ever pronounce the "he'd" or would they just say "he" if they were to say "he'd better get used to it"?

Answer (score 1):

It's common for speakers to use 1. The sound difference is not great. If you're writing to represent such speech, you could write it that way. If you're writing more formally, *you'd* better use the form *he'd*.